# summarize data from csv using R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, summary

I'm new to R, and I wrote some code to summarize data from .csv file according to my needs.

here is the code.

```
raw <- read.csv("trees.csv")
```

looks like this

```
                                 SNAME     CNAME        FAMILY PLOT INDIVIDUAL CAP   H
1 Alchornea triplinervia (Spreng.) M. Arg. Tainheiro Euphorbiaceae    5        176  15 9.5
2               Andira fraxinifolia Benth.   Angelim      Fabaceae    3        321  12 6.0
3               Andira fraxinifolia Benth.   Angelim      Fabaceae    3        326  14 7.0
4               Andira fraxinifolia Benth.   Angelim      Fabaceae    3        327  18 5.0
5               Andira fraxinifolia Benth.   Angelim      Fabaceae    3        328  12 6.0
6               Andira fraxinifolia Benth.   Angelim      Fabaceae    3        329  21 7.0

#add 2 other rows
for (i in 1:nrow(raw)) {
  raw$VOLUME[i] <- treeVolume(raw$CAP[i],raw$H[i])  
  raw$BASALAREA[i] <- treeBasalArea(raw$CAP[i])
}
```

#here comes.
I need a new data frame, with the mean of columns H and CAP and the sums of columns VOLUME and BASALAREA. This dataframe is grouped by column SNAME and subgrouped by column PLOT.

```
plotSummary = merge(
  aggregate(raw$CAP ~ raw$SNAME * raw$PLOT, raw, mean),
  aggregate(raw$H ~ raw$SNAME * raw$PLOT, raw, mean))

plotSummary = merge(
  plotSummary,
  aggregate(raw$VOLUME ~ raw$SNAME * raw$PLOT, raw, sum))


plotSummary = merge(
  plotSummary,
  aggregate(raw$BASALAREA ~ raw$SNAME * raw$PLOT, raw, sum))
```

The functions treeVolume  and treeBasal area just return numbers.

```
treeVolume <- function(radius, height) {
  return (0.000074230*radius**1.707348*height**1.16873)
}

treeBasalArea <- function(radius) {
  return (((radius**2)*pi)/40000)
}
```

I'm sure that there is a better way of doing this, but how?

Comment: replace the ugly 4 aggregate by something less repetitious

Comment: @user1424495 While it's good to see what you've tried so we have an idea of what to improve on, if you think your code is "ugly" then maybe you could tell us in words what is does. The comment `#here comes` doesn't help much.

Comment: And, to make your code reproducible, we either need the functions `treeVolume` and `treeBasalArea` or the results of their calls.

Comment: updated my answer in light of your last revision. It should hopefully be more intuitive *and* faster than your current solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't manage to read your example data in, but I think I've made something that generally represents it...so give this a whirl. This answer builds off of Greg's suggestion to look at plyr and the functions `ddply` to group by segments of your data.frame and `numcolwise` to calculate your statistics of interest.

```
#Sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(sname = rep(letters[1:3],2), plot = rep(letters[1:3],2), 
                  CAP = rnorm(6), 
                  H = rlnorm(6), 
                  VOLUME = runif(6),
                  BASALAREA = rlnorm(6)
                  )


#Calculate mean for all numeric columns, grouping by sname and plot
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, c("sname", "plot"), numcolwise(mean))
#-----
  sname plot        CAP        H    VOLUME BASALAREA
1     a    a  0.4844135 1.182481 0.3248043  1.614668
2     b    b  0.2565755 3.313614 0.6279025  1.397490
3     c    c -0.8280485 1.627634 0.1768697  2.538273
```

## EDIT - response to updated question

Ok - now that your question is more or less reproducible, here's how I'd approach it. First of all, you can take advantage of the fact that R is a [vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445059/vectorize-my-thinking-vector-operations-in-r) meaning that you can calculate ALL of the values from VOLUME and BASALAREA in one pass, without looping through each row. For that bit, I recommend the `transform` function:

```
dat <- transform(dat, VOLUME = treeVolume(CAP, H), BASALAREA = treeBasalArea(CAP))
```

Secondly, realizing that you intend to calculate different statistics for CAP & H and then VOLUME & BASALAREA, I recommend using the `summarize` function, like this:

```
ddply(dat, c("sname", "plot"), summarize,
  meanCAP = mean(CAP),
  meanH = mean(H),
  sumVOLUME = sum(VOLUME),
  sumBASAL = sum(BASALAREA)
  )
```

Which will give you an output that looks like:

```
  sname plot   meanCAP     meanH    sumVOLUME     sumBASAL
1     a    a 0.5868582 0.5032308 9.650184e-06 7.031954e-05
2     b    b 0.2869029 0.4333862 9.219770e-06 1.407055e-05
3     c    c 0.7356215 0.4028354 2.482775e-05 8.916350e-05
```

The help pages for `?ddply, ?transform, ?summarize` should be insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `plyr` package.  I will split the data by the SNAME variable for you, then you give it code to do the set of summaries that you want (mixing mean and sum and whatever), then it will put the pieces back together for you.  You probably want either the 'ddply' or the 'daply' function in that package.