# Reg ex searching of csv file,

Tags: regex

I have huge task to do, seperating Voltage data from recorded .csv files of the format.

13/03/2014 18:48,71.556671,71.651062,71.639755,72.130692,71.961441,72.646423,72.262756,72.334511,7.812012

I am new to RegExpressions, how do i get data from column 10, repeatedly? 
I have over 10,000,000 files to reduce and average to 32,000 for exel to graph. Any advice greatly welcome, trying to use PowerGrep to get up to speed.

Comment: You absolutely don't want to use regex for that. Use a programming language with a proper CSV parser.

Comment: You could use R, for example. R has got facilities to read in CSV data and the capability process large amounts of data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805295/summarize-data-from-csv-using-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I would say that regex is *the* tool for it, but here goes:

```
(?:[^,]*,){9}([^,]*)
```

I.e. nine "columns" of non-commas, separated by commas, then capture the tenth in group 1.

E.g. use it with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; /(?:[^,]*,){9}([^,]*)/ and print "$1\n"'
```